# Find all parameters $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ for which the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a) has a limit at point 0 b) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

My function $f: \mathbb R  \rightarrow \mathbb R$ it is given a pattern:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \frac{2^{7^{x}-1}-a}{\ln(1-x)},& x<0\\ b,& x=0 \\ \frac{\sin\left(c \sqrt{x^{2}+d^{2}x}\right) }{x},& x>0  \end{cases}$$ for $$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$$
I have a problem with this task because function patterns for $x</>0$ have they reach zero in the denominator for $x=0.$

That is why I think that I should cut a denominator with a numerator but I cannot do it because I have logarithm and sine so I need other way to this task.

I thought about doing some substitution: for example $y=\frac{1}{x}$, then for $x \rightarrow 0^\mp$ I have $y \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and but I still can not solve this.

Can I count on any tips?

Comment: so the goal is to find the parameters such that the function defined for x negative, x positive and x = 0 is continuous ?

Comment: @MP3129 Are you familiar with [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @MarineGalantin in point (a) I need to find the parameters $ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R $ for which the function has a limit in point 0 and in point (b) which is a separate case I have to indicate parameters for which the function is continuous in the whole field

Comment: @CameronBuie I have not a Taylor's Theorem at my university and I mustn't use facts which I did not have a lecture

Comment: @MP3129: Okay. What about L'Hôpital's Rule?

Comment: @CameronBuie No, I saw in my script that this claims are only in the next section (on analysis I.2 and I am at I.1)

Comment: @MP3129 It will be difficult for us to help you without knowing what results you have available to you, unfortunately. Have you any results at all that allow you to determine a limit when both numerator and denominator tend to $0$?

Comment: @CameronBuie Unfortunately I haven't no claims - we were given only the basic features of the function boundary at the point and continuity, and then we were asked to do this task ...

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that as $x\nearrow 0,$ the denominator $\ln(1-x)$ vanishes, so the only way to avoid $\bigl|f(x)\bigr|\to+\infty$ in that case is to make sure that the numerator vanishes as well. Since $$2^{7^x-1}-a\to2^{7^0-1}-a=2^{1-1}-a=2^0-a=1-a,$$ this means we must put $a=1$ to accomplish this.

If you're familiar with the result that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}t=1,\tag{1}$$ then we can tackle the right-hand limit as follows. Since $\lim_{x\searrow0}c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}=0,$ then by $(1)$ we have $$\lim_{x\searrow0}\frac{\sin\left(c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}\right)}{c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}}=1,$$ so, since $$\frac{\sin\left(c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}\right)}{x}=\frac{\sin\left(c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}\right)}{c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}}\cdot\frac{c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}}{x}=\frac{\sin\left(c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}\right)}{c\sqrt{x^2+d^2x}}\cdot c\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}x}$$ whenever $x>0,$ then $\lim_{x\searrow0}f(x)=+\infty$ unless $d=0,$ in which case the limit is $c.$ Thus, for the right-hand limit to exist, we require $d=0.$ Moreover, for the two-sided limit to exist, we need $a=1,$ $d=0,$ and $c=\lim_{x\nearrow0}f(x),$ assuming the left-hand limit exists.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with any elementary ways to proceed further. Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) allows us to find that $$\begin{eqnarray}\lim_{x\nearrow0}\frac{2^{7^x-1}-1}{\ln(1-x)} &=& \lim_{x\nearrow0}\cfrac{\ln(2)\ln(7)7^{x}2^{7x-1}}{-\frac1{1-x}}\\ &=& \lim_{x\nearrow0}(x-1)\ln(2)\ln(7)7^{x}2^{7x-1}\\ &=& (0-1)\ln(2)\ln(7)7^{0}2^{0-1}\\ &=& -\frac{\ln(2)\ln(7)}2,\end{eqnarray}$$ so for the two-sided limit to exist, we require $a=1,$ $c=\frac{\ln(2)\ln(7)}2,$ and $d=0.$ For continuity, we additionally require $b=\frac{\ln(2)\ln(7)}2.$